# Equivalents of XDG_CONFIG_HOME and XDG_DATA_HOME on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, configuration-files, xdgutils

I am planning to develop a cross-platform script. On Linux and other operating systems, it will store configuration in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and data files (specifically, downloaded plugins) in `XDG_DATA_HOME`. On Windows, it will use `APPDATA` for both (unless someone has a better idea). However, what would be the proper thing to do on Mac OS X?

On my first glance through a handy Macbook's `~/Library` directory, I saw `Preferences` and `Application Support` folders. I was originally planning to use those, but `Preferences` seems to just contain plists with reverse domain names like `com.apple.foo.bar.baz.plist`, and every folder in `Application Support` corresponds to a bundle in `/Applications`, so I'm not sure how well the system would react to files that don't match its standards. Storing them directly in `~/Library` might be an option, but I don't want to pollute it with a stray `myscript.conf` file if there's a better place for it.

Where should I store these files? (And please don't say just `~/.myscript`. I know it's the Unix tradition, but it annoys me to see random dotfiles in the home directory.)

Comment: If it's a command line tool, or otherwise used by developers, *please please please* just use the XDG directories. Or at least use them if they exist, even if you fall back to `~/Library` as a default instead of `~/.config` et al.

Comment: Wouldn’t you want command-line tools and scripts separate from macOS apps (I presume obj-c and swift have their source for getting this information)  so rather than ~/Library use  ~./config ~/local ~/.cache ? The only thing I haven't worked out is if those tools are shared between multiple user if shared data should be under /usr/local/share. XDG doest seem to distinguish user and system options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `~/Library/Application Support/script_name/`.  The subdirectories inside `Application Support` are used conventionally by various apps, including Apple's own softwares. But it's not enforced by the OS and not tied to apps inside `/Applications`.  So  you're perfectly free to create your own directory in it.

For the directory structure of OS X in general, see [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html).

Comment: Okay, cool. Is this suitable for configuration as well, or just data files?

Comment: Both are fine. I added to the answer an official document as a reference.

Comment: Link seems to be outdated, maybe this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 56):

Comparing Apple's documentation for the various paths to the XDG Base Directory specifications approximates to the following locations:

- `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` ▶︎ `~/Library/Preferences/`
- `XDG_DATA_HOME`  ▶︎ `~/Library/`
- `XDG_CACHE_HOME` ▶︎ `~/Library/Caches/`

Mapping XDG Base Directory Specification locations for "My App" on Mac OS X could look like this:

- `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` ▶︎ `~/Library/Preferences/name.often.with.domain.myapp.plist`
- `XDG_DATA_HOME` ▶︎ `~/Library/My App/`
- `XDG_CACHE_HOME` ▶︎ `~/Library/Caches/My App/`

These mappings seem pretty reasonable but they aren't exact. Some kinds of cache or data may be appropriate for `~/Library/Application Support/My App`, and other may be best in the temp locations or the App bundle. All of it is by convention and the same reasons for using the best `XDG_` locations apply to using the best locations on the Mac OS X system.

Your annoyance at `~/.myscript` is in line with Apple's guidelines: "Don't pollute user space".

References:

- [Mac OS X Reference Library: Where to Put Application Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html)
- [Mac OS X Reference Library: Important Java Directories on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/)

Comment: XDG_*_HOME aren't app-specific — your examples should probably read "XDG_CONFIG_HOME -> ~/Library/Preferences/", "XDG_DATA_HOME -> ~/Library/", & "XDG_CACHE_HOME -> ~/Library/Caches/". (Your post was helpful though! I'm just providing this minor correction for posterity)

Comment: The examples were locations for "My App". I've added a generic mapping to the answer that shows the non app-specific locations. Thanks.

Comment: Links seem to be outdated, was it something like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1

Comment: Link update: [Mac OS X Reference Library: Important Java Directories on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1170/_index.html)

Comment: I dont think there is really a standard for non-gui under macOS. I would be more inclined to keep command-line and scripts in accordance to UNIX/LINUX ~/.cache ~./config ~local seem to have become favourites. macOS applications have there own specification ~/Library for example Xcode, objective-c and swift.

Comment: And `XDG_STATE_HOME` ▶︎ `~/Library/Application\ Support`? And I agree with @AndrewC, the collision potential would be great if you set it this way. Better keep it separated.

Answer (score 25):

I agree with [OJFord's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373948/equivalents-of-xdg-config-home-and-xdg-data-home-on-mac-os-x/5084892#comment67156521_3373948): if you are writing a **script** (I think this applies to all CLI-only application), simply follow the XDG Base Directory would be better.

Rationales:

1. Names in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` are typically small-case bare-names like `git`; the ones in `~/Library/Preferences/` are typically files named with [reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) like `com.apple.AppStore.plist`, or directories named in [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case) like `Blackmagic Design`.
2. GUI applications have been following macOS conventions when they are placed in `/Applications`. You don't place your script in `/Applications`; you place them in [UNIX-specific directorys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW7). Better to be consistent.
3. `~/Library/Preferences/` is full of `.plist`s. No cross-platform script that I know is using property lists.
4. Users may want to sync cross-platform configuration and macOS-only one separately.

For example, Git places their config file in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`, not in `~/Library/Preferences/Git/config`. Makes sense to me.

#### note

I made the point only for configuration files (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`) and data files (`$XDG_DATA_HOME`); for cache files it gets subtle. According to [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/294600/save-space-on-your-time-machine-drive-by-excluding-these-folders-from-backups/), `~/Library/Caches` directory is excluded from [Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(macOS)) by default. I don’t care about cache folder since I back up neither directories anyway; but for ones who care, I recommend them to link `~/.cache` to somewhere in the default cache folder, such as:

```sh
cd ~; mv .cache ~/Library/Caches/XDG-cache; ln -s ~/Library/Caches/XDG-cache .cache
```

Comment: Could not agree more. I hope more scripts and CLI programs adopt XDG across all *nix platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [choices](https://pkg.go.dev/os#UserCacheDir) made by the `os` package in `golang`:

- `XDG_CACHE_HOME` → `$HOME/Library/Caches`
- `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`  → `$HOME/Library/Application Support`