# Global Git ignore

Tags: git, global, gitignore

I want to set up Git to globally ignore certain files.

I have added a `.gitignore` file to my home directory (`/Users/me/`) and I have added the following line to it:

```
*.tmproj
```

But it is not ignoring this type of files, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might also want to check out GitHub's ignore suggestions -- https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files; they have a [repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore) of common ignore patterns

Comment: You may also want to consider just using a .gitignore inside individual projects. Otherwise if you (or someone else) clone the project on a new system, you'll also have to recreate the global excludesfile and configuration each time.

Comment: I totally agree with @StanKurdziel. I can't think of a good reason to use a global .gitignore file. *Maybe* if you have a project with people using a huge variety of editors and IDE's you *might* not want to clutter the project's .gitignore with all kinds of things tailored to each IDE... but frankly I'd live with the clutter.

Comment: Ignorable files that the project creates should be in the project .gitignore file, ignorable files that stuff on your machine creates should go in the global .gitignore (like editor/IDE temp files and the like).

Comment: Python virtual environment directories are a common use case for entries in my global or local excludesfile.

Comment: @Pylinux Actually, per [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), personal IDE and workflow specific stuff can go in the untracked file `.git/info/exclude` in the repo, so it doesn't necessarily have to go in the global file. Also, the default and automatic global gitignore file is `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`.

Comment: see video here https://youtu.be/3LYBdd3RGKs

Comment: @Asclepius Great solution but there is a caveat: Unfortunately, because of IMHO some git silliness regarding adding patterns into .git/info/exclude for files which have already had changes made to them, the user will notice that the file still is not being ignored :-( .. A couple of solutions may be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882445/files-in-git-info-exclude-not-work .. The "update-index --assume-unchanged" solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2014, accepted):

You need to set up your global `core.excludesfile` configuration file to point to this global ignore file e.g:

***nix or Windows git bash:**

```
git config --global core.excludesFile '~/.gitignore'
```

**Windows cmd:**

```
git config --global core.excludesFile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore"
```

**Windows PowerShell:**

```
git config --global core.excludesFile "$Env:USERPROFILE\.gitignore"
```

For Windows it is set to the location `C:\Users\%username%\.gitignore`. You can verify that the config value is correct by doing:

```
git config --global core.excludesFile
```

The result should be the expanded path to your user profile's `.gitignore`. Ensure that the value does not contain the unexpanded `%USERPROFILE%` string.

**Important**: The above commands will only set the location of the ignore file that git will use. The file has to still be manually created in that location and populated with the ignore list. (from [muruge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265881/muruge)'s comment)

You can read about the command at https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files#configuring-ignored-files-for-all-repositories-on-your-computer

Comment: I have done this, then I `rm`ed the *.tmproj, resaved the file and it still shows up as an untracked change

Comment: @MildFuzz: Do you mean that it's showing up in `git status` under `Untracked files:` ?  This shouldn't happen, I've just done a quick test on my system and it works as expected for me.

Comment: Will it be because the file has been tracked in the past?

Comment: So long as it's not in your `HEAD` or your index it shouldn't make any difference whether the file was once tracked or not. It may be helpful if you add the output of `git status`, `git config core.excludesfile` to your question.

Comment: Since there are several levels of configuration (system, global, local), you should check to find out your "effective" core.excludesfile. Type: `git config core.excludesfile`. You may find that it refers to something like `$HOME/.gitignore_global`.

Comment: Can I use `#` at the beginning of lines inside `~/.gitignore` to add comments inside the global ignore file?

Comment: Recent versions of the official Git Windows toolkit use the *nix syntax instead; if this line doesn't work, try the *nix one instead.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work using the `%USERPROFILE%` variable.  I had to enter the full path to the file using *nix directory separators.  e.g. core.excludesfile C:/Users/User/.gitignore

Comment: You can also try `%HOME%` instead of `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: Couldn't get it working with %USERPROFILE% variable. I had to use git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore' in windows to get it set to the location C:/users/{myusername}/.gitignore. Also the above command will only set the location of the ignore file that git will use. The file has to still be manually created in that location and populated with the ignore list.

Comment: Note: This works in CMD on my Windows 7, but DOES NOT work in PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, it should be noted that if you're running this from git bash on Windows, you should use `~/.gitignore` as well. The `%USERPROFILE%` var will work in `cmd`.

Comment: Remember if you apply this change after the fact then you'll need to [clear your repo's cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working) for the change to take effect.

Comment: The quotes are actually not required, you could simply go `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`. At least on Git 1.9.4 that is.

Comment: in my case %USERPROFILE% didn't work. I tried with and without quotes. I think it's taking it as part of the filename. I ended up swapping in the actual location behind the alias and that is working.

Comment: Hello @CharlesBailey, thanks for your answer. I've set my global `gitignore` long ago and today I have an opposite problem: can I ignore my global `gitignore` :). I have one repo that I need to push an `.exe` file. I don't wan't to change my global config for just one repo. Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry to bother! I just got it working with command `git config --local core.excludesfile ""`. Thanks anyway, great answer. If you find like it, you can add this addendum to it. May be helpful. See you.

Comment: On windows, be careful about the quotes when you copy the example above.  Make sure you are using normal " quotes in your command.  I copied the example and it gave me special quote characters which git thought was part of my path making it appear not to work.

Comment: Can I negate global `.gitignore` for example if I have `/src/` in global ignores? But for one single project I want to have `!/src/` will this work?

Comment: `~/.gitignore` works on WSL (windows subsystem for linux) too

Comment: As a side note, there is also the option to set a repo specific ignore list without committing it to the repo, using a file set in the `.git` folder of the repo, which will just stay local to you. See https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files#excluding-local-files-without-creating-a-gitignore-file

Comment: Beware that there is already **default location** that `git` uses for this file. And doing this is *overwriting it*. I would recommend just using the default. See this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885996/9849440

Answer (score 453):

Although other answers are correct they are setting the global config value whereas there is a default git location for the global git ignore file.

You can check if the global gitignore exists via:

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

Typically, it is found in these locations on different operating systems:

*nix:

```
~/.config/git/ignore
```

Windows:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.config\git\ignore
```

You may need to create the `git` directory and `ignore` file and tell git the location via `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.config/git/ignore` but then you can put your global ignores into that file and that's it!

[Source](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> Which file to place a pattern in depends on how the pattern is meant to be used.

…

> - Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by `core.excludesFile` in the user’s `~/.gitconfig`. Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/ignore is used instead.

Comment: This is great; I didn't know about this... however isn't this a generated file? Can it be overwritten when you update/re-install?

Comment: I believe the file is created/modified by running certain `git` commands. Since it is a settings file in each user's directory, I don't think that it should ever be overwritten.

Comment: I agree this should be the accepted answer, however I didn't find this in -t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶  a help article (https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: @AVProgrammer I just edited the answer to reflect the change in how the source doc is organized.

Comment: @Cas do you have the source for the Windows path? It does not work for me.

Comment: Looks like on Windows the path is also `~/.config/git/ignore`.

Comment: After doing this do I still need to run `git config --global core.excludesfile`?

Comment: On macOS this does not work by default. As the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) states: `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore, $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, .gitignore` are parsed, but `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set by default on macOS. Thus, if `git config --get core.excludesfile` doesn't output the folder it didn't work and you have to set it manually to `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.config/git/ignore` or actually any other location that's convenient for you.

Comment: Using this default ignore file is nice on Windows because it will be used by both Git for Windows and the Git that comes with Cygwin.

Comment: For me, the `core.excludesFile` was *not* set to any value by default. (I checked before making any changes and the setting had no value) So, users may still need to set the `core.excludesFile` setting, even if using the listed paths.

Comment: works by default on macOS `git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)`.

Comment: This is surely the best answer, is there any way to override the accepted one? A lot of people will end up making their lives more complex than they need to if they follow the other answers...

Comment: works by default on Mac OS X
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

Comment: The location of the ~/.config file may be customized by setting the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable. Seems that [on macOS, it is almost a must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749090/2157640).

Answer (score 379):

Before reconfiguring the global excludes file, you might want to check what it's currently configured to, using this command:

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

In my case, when I ran it I saw my global excludes file was configured to

```
~/.gitignore_global
```

and there were already a couple things listed there. So in the case of the given question, it might make sense to first check for an existing excludes file, and add the new file mask to it.

Comment: There is a default location git looks for this file and `git config --get core.excludesFile` does not return it, unfortunately. What is currently "configured" if nothing is returned from that is something like `~/.config/git/ignore`. See this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885996/9849440

Answer (score 70):

To create global gitignore from scratch:

```
$ cd ~
$ touch .gitignore_global
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

1. First line changes directory to `C:/Users/User`
2. After that you create an empty file with `.gitignore_global` extension
3. And finally setting global ignore to that file.
4. Then you should open it with some kind of notepad and add the needed ignore rules.

Answer (score 51):

1. Create a .gitignore file in your home directory

```
touch ~/.gitignore
```

2. Add files/folders to it

Example

```
# Files
*.gz
*.tmproj
*.7z

# Folders
.vscode/
build/

# If folders don't work, you can still do this
.vscode/*
build/*
```

3. Check if a git already has a global gitignore

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

4. Tell git where the file is

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'
```

Voila!!

Comment: It seems that name of the file doesn't matter & I found that Kent. C Dodds named this file `.gitignore_global`, isn't that is the better option eliminating little chance of collision with real .gitignore?

Comment: I.m.o it might just be better to append your stuff to the real .gitignore even if it does exist.

Answer (score 26):

From [here](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/).

If you create a file in your repo named .gitignore git will use its rules when looking at files to commit. **Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a rule was added to this file to ignore it.** In such a case the file must be un-tracked, usually with :

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Is it your case ?

Comment: I am trying to ignore globally, which is not happening!!

Comment: @MildFuzz on Linux the `core.excludesfile` file seems to be interpreted differently than a `.gitignore` file. If you want to ignore an entire directory just put the name of the directory like `.vscode/` instead of `.vscode/*`

Answer (score 15):

If you use Unix system, you can solve your problem in two commands.
Where the first initialize configs and the second alters file with a file to ignore.

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
$ echo '.idea' >> ~/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 12):

Remember that running the command

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'
```

will just set up the global file, but will NOT create it.
For Windows check your Users directory for the `.gitconfig` file, and edit it to your preferences. In my case It's like that:

```
[core]
  excludesfile = c:/Users/myuser/Dropbox/Apps/Git/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 5):

I am able to ignore a `.tmproj` file by including either `.tmproj` or `*.tmproj` in my `/users/me/.gitignore-global` file.

Note that the file name is `.gitignore-global` not `.gitignore`.  It did not work by including `.tmproj` or `*.tmproj` in a file called `.gitignore` in the `/users/me` directory.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call your global ignore file so long as it matches your `core.excludesfile` config.

Comment: Ah! Good point @CharlesBailey.  However this may be something the writer may want to check.  The reason the `.tmproj` file is not getting ignored may be because the user's `excludesfile` is not be `.gitignore`.

Comment: I guess he thought the user would be smart enough to realise.

Comment: This should have more upvotes, I had the same issue with my git not reconizing the .gitignore globally, just because its name was .gitignore too... So I decided to change it to .gitignore_global and change the "core.excludesfile" to point to that new file and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You should create an exclude file for this. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/221353) which is pretty self explanatory.

To address your question though, you may need to either de-index the `.tmproj` file (if you've already added it to the index) with `git rm --cached path/to/.tmproj`, or `git add` and `commit` your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I am trying to do this globally, not just per repo

Comment: Yeah, that's what I linked to in the gist. I was a little confused by the original question. Did you do the `git rm --cached` ?

Comment: yeah, tried that. It seems to me I have followed all the recommended advice! What am I missing?

Comment: As suggested, I'd add your git status and excludes info to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

on windows subsystem for linux I had to navigate to the subsystem root by `cd ~/` then `touch .gitignore` and then update the global gitignore configuration in there.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default global gitignore file that is located here (in POSIX systems):

`~/.config/git/ignore`

If you don't want to change your git config

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution if the `.gitignore` approach isn't working for you is to:

```sh
git update-index --skip-worktree path_to_file
```

That will ignore changes to that file, both local and upstream, until you decide to allow them again with:

```sh
git update-index --no-skip-worktree path_to_file
```

You can get a list of files that are marked skipped with:

```sh
git ls-files -v . | grep ^S
```

Note that unlike `--skip-worktree`, the `--assume-unchanged` status will get lost once an upstream change is pulled.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using VSCODE, you can get this extension to handle the task for you.
It watches your workspace each time you save your work and helps you to automatically ignore the files and folders you specified in your vscode settings.json
[ignoreit (vscode extension)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marcdomain.ignoreit)