# How do I add a global gitignore to SmartGit/hg?

Tags: git, smartgit

I created a global `.gitignore`  file (see https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#global-gitignore) but how can I make this used for all my projects in SmartGit without adding it to the repositories?

Comment: Did you configure the global gitignore file (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420)? If it works for command line, it will work for SmartGit as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [global git ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)

Comment: thx, it worked like in that answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you configure

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'
```

This also takes effect on Smartgit

Comment: [@Dirk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2324028/dirk): you [sugested to remove the quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12391029), why?