# Is "tags" a reserved keyword in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

One of my projects has a sub folder called "tags". As it looks like, this folder is ignored by git although I've not defined it in my .gitignore file.

So I guess there is a list of "keywords" like "tags" that is ignored by git on default?

Here is the content of the .gitignore file

```
# Java: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore
*.class
**/classes/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# IDEA: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/IntelliJ.gitignore

*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Mac OS X: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/OSX.gitignore

.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes

# Gradle
.gradle/
**/build/
out/

# Leiningen and others
**/target/
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `git status --untracked-files=all` as well as `ls -1 /your/missing/directory` and (if necessary) point out which files are expected to show up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tags` is a good candidate for a global ignore rule because of its use by the `ctags` command.

`ctags` generates an index of identifiers in your source code and writes them to a file called `tags`, which `vi` uses to quickly jump to the definition of the identifier under your cursor when you press `^]`. For this reason, lots of source directories tend to contain a `tags` file that is not of interest to version control.

Do you have a global ignore file set up? [An answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore) suggests:

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

to find out.

And reading further down the answers in that other question: also `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` and `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`

Comment: You were absolutely right: `git config --get core.excludesfile` gave me `~/.yadr/git/gitignore` which contains a tags element. Thx!

Comment: To not exclude tags _directories_, you can add `!tags/` after `tags` in your excludes.

Comment: oh thank you for this, I totally forgot I had a global git ignore file where I had added "tags" because of my use of ctags (which I no longer use). My site built using Hugo uses a "tags" directory for cross referencing categories and so this had me very confused when I discovered clicking on a tag link on my site was 404'ing :-)

Answer (score 4):

All files that are special (e.g. `.gitignore`) to git have names beginning with `.git` and except for the `.git/` directory itself even these special files get tracked.

Do you have any files in your `tags/` folder? Empty directories don't get tracked by git.

Additionally the file or a matching pattern could be defined in `.git/info/exclude`. This is like the `.gitignore` file but doesn't get tracked itself. I use that e.g. for ignoring temporary files from my editor.

Comment: It's probably an empty directory, I just tested it and tags/ is normally listed if you put a file in it

Comment: no, it's not an empty folder. Actually it's a folder representing a java package. In some deeper sub folders there are several java files. After I renamed tags to tagging, files and folders were also listed

Comment: .git/info/excludes is empty as well

Answer (score 1):

Normally that should work if you have files inside the folder and the folder isn't ignored.

The function in git is *tag* so that should not make any problems. All git files are in the *.git* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use **git check-ignore [FILE]**

I hit the same idea like as the questioner, but it was not correct!

Check with the following method!

```
# for registered as ignore, show which file the definition is set in.
$ git check-ignore -v tags
/PATH/TO/DIR/.config/git/ignore:2:tags  tags

$ git check-ignore -v no-registered-tags # for not registered, outputs nothing.
```

---

**My condition**

```
$ git --version
git version 2.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep the "tags" in `.gitignore` but exclude only my directory

So I added this line:

```
# Auto-generated tag files
tags
!myproject/path/tags/
```

That **last line** excludes only my projects "tags" directory