# files in .git/info/exclude not work

Tags: git, github

I've put two files in `.git/info/exclude` but I can still see them with a `git st`

They are a config files, and I don't want to commit more.
I put them there because with `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree` I can not checkout to another branch.

Answer (score 15):

If a file which already in the GIT repo, is excluded using `.git/info/exclude`, you need to run `git update-index --assume-unchanged <path-of-the-excluded-file>` to ignore further changes.

Comment: As OP says, `--assume-unchanged` then prevents checking out another branch, so this only solves half of the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

> I can still see them with a git st

That means they are still versioned: you need to remove them from the index first:

```
git rm --cached -- yourConfigFile
git add .
git commit -m "Record deletion of yourConfigfile"
```

Then the `git status` would ignore those files.

Comment: Thanks @vonc. One question, if I remove them from the index, do they disappear from the remote repository when I push this `rm`?. I only want that my local modifications from this config files not affect to remotes and not to see every time `git st`

Comment: @JohnFadria yes, they would be removed on the remote as well. If you want only local ignore, the `git update-index` you mentioned would be a better fit.

Comment: yes @vonc but with `update-index` every time I want to change the branch I have to `stash` them....

Comment: I think It's not an answer on current question.