# Nothing to commit - Git

Tags: git, git-commit

I have created a new repository on github for a project, cloned it and pushed 2 files: README.md and main.c.

But for some reason every time I try to use

```
 git status
```

or

```
git add .
```

to commit changes, I get the following message

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So I can't push anything and the only workaround solution that works is

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git remote add origin <repo>
```

and force pushing the files. After I push the changes it goes back to the 'nothing to commit' message,so I have to reinitialise every time I want to commit.

This problem occurs even when I try to reclone the repository.

I've looked around for solutions, it seems that .gitignore can sometimes cause similar issues but I don't have a .gitignore file in the repo.

Comment: You said that you cloned **and committed** 2 files. Therefore, it is expected that after running "git add ." you'll get "nothing to commit".

Comment: Maybe a global ignore file? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7335420/2404501 - or more likely @l19 is right and you're not doing the whole "modify, `git add`, `git status`, `git commit`" sequence in the right order.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I don't have a global ignore file on my machine either.. I've been using git for a year now and I am quite familiar with how to commit and push files, so I really don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the output of `git status -s --ignored`?  If you see anything with a `!!` at the front, then that means it's being ignored somehow.  You have to explicitly add anything that is being ignored.  Moreover, you have to use `git add -f` to force it, otherwise git will yell at you saying the file is being ignored.  For example: `git add -f path/to/ignored_file.txt`