# Github Nothing to Commit

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to upload a new project to Github. I created the repository and git bashed on the repository folder. But when I use these two commands I get the following errors:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
On branch master
Initial commit    
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'repolink.git'
```

I tried that command:  `git push --set-upstream origin main`

I got the same error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'repolink.git'
```

How can I fix this problem? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

-----UPDATE-----

I tried the answer in the following question:
[Nothing to commit - Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172689/nothing-to-commit-git)

And it worked! Thank you all...

Comment: Did you add the files you want to commit before committing?

Comment: Yes, I did. I was checking other questions related to that problem and I saw that command: git status -s --ignored
I have a .gitignore file. Can that be the root of my problem?

Comment: The .gitignore contains a vlacklist with files that can't be added. If you cannot add anything, you cannot commit.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can see here.

1. It seems that you try to commit without any files. So you probably need to use `git add` before to add at least one new file or call `git commit -am` which automatically adds all modified tracked files.
2. Your status shows "On branch master". With this I guess you also need to do `git push -u origin master`. The `master` to `main` renaming was recently introduced by GitHub, so not sure if they automatically consider this.

Comment: 1. On branch master
Initial commit    
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
2. error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'repolink.git'
I tried them, it didn't work.

Comment: What do you get when you do a `git status`? The second error might be caused as a consequence of the first as you cannot push when there are not commits to push.

Comment: On branch main
No commits yet
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

I got this.

Comment: This means that you currently don't have any files in the repositroy. Maybe you start with a `touch README.md` and add this with `git add README.md`. Then you should be able to commit and push.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to push to `main` but your local git is under branch `master`.
I would check my local repository status and tool versions.

Try `git status` to understand what is happening in your local, and `git remote -v` to determine where and what happens in remote.