# Manage vim-plugin using git submodule and pathogen

Tags: vim, git-submodules, vim-plugin, pathogen

I use github to store my dotvim 
https://github.com/mingchaoyan/dotvim

Pathogen is my choice to manage vim-plugins. To generate vim tags, pathogen tells me to add

```
call pathogen#helptags()
```

into vimrc. It generates tags for each plugin. When I type

```
 git status
```

git points me some untracked file. They are tags generated by helptags.

To make my working copy clean, I do

```
git add xxx/doc/tags
git ca ...
git push
```

but another problem appears.
When I try to clone dotvim on another computer,

```
git clone https://github.com/mingchaoyan/dotvim
...
git submodule init
git submodule update 


fatal: reference is not a tree: 0cca328d1a6b12422026e62c3fb8951e22f70b80
fatal: reference is not a tree: 812b8c9e59a5e917f1e206ce4b3d2bcf3391bb11
fatal: reference is not a tree: a3d7e4533871e76b9cadd85177dc84aad7503154
fatal: reference is not a tree: 82a3aa42ff799de33739685551771decd05157de
fatal: reference is not a tree: ef95accdee67b43396fcc65cb65eed0d9668c9de
fatal: reference is not a tree: cb9b7a395a79dd5633eeb789bc809faf6977118d
Unable to checkout '0cca328d1a6b12422026e62c3fb8951e22f70b80' in submodule path 'bundle/DrawIt'
Unable to checkout '812b8c9e59a5e917f1e206ce4b3d2bcf3391bb11' in submodule path 'bundle/SingleCompil
e'
Unable to checkout 'a3d7e4533871e76b9cadd85177dc84aad7503154' in submodule path 'bundle/lookupfile'
Unable to checkout '82a3aa42ff799de33739685551771decd05157de' in submodule path 'bundle/snipmate'
Unable to checkout 'ef95accdee67b43396fcc65cb65eed0d9668c9de' in submodule path 'bundle/taglist'
Unable to checkout 'cb9b7a395a79dd5633eeb789bc809faf6977118d' in submodule path 'bundle/vcscommand'
```

These are the plugins I just add.

I may know the reason is the submodule on my repo is different from the original one with "tags".
How can I manage vim-plugins with pathogen and gitsubmodule without above problem？

Comment: I think a better solution would be to ignore the generated tags via `.gitignore` instead of committing them; in any case, I don't think that `git push` works as expected, as you'd need to set up writable clones for the submodules.

Comment: Create a global gitignore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore. Then add tags to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a Git submodule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)