# Git ignore mongod.log

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb

I tried several different combinations, but I was not able to exclude the mongodb log from git.

My gitignore:

```
mongodb/data/
mongodb/data/log/mongod.log
mongodb/data/**/*.log
/mongodb/data/**/*.log
```

None of them work. When I type

> git status

I still get the following:

> modified:   mongodb/data/log/mongod.log

How can I ignore this file?
The data under mongodb/data/db is ignored. I do not understand why the log file is constantly showing up again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: This is one of the most frequently asked questions on the [tag:git] tag, please ensure to use the search before asking new questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have a file in the git tree, it's not enough to add it to the `.gitignore` file, as it still belongs to the tree and git will take care of.

The `.gitignore` file is intended to be used before you add files to the tree.

In your situation you have to remove the file from the tree with:

```
git rm path/to/file
```

You also will have to commit the deletion.

If you want to keep a copy where it is at the moment, move it to /tmp, issue a git status (it should be marked as deleted), make a commit and move it again to the original place.

I'd suggest to use the global git configuration for widely used common files that are likely to be ignored in other projects. You can check out this question: [Global Git ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)