# How to git ignore ipython notebook checkpoints anywhere in repository

Tags: git, commit, gitignore, jupyter-notebook

This is mostly a git question. I want to commit my ipython notebooks but gitignore the checkpoints.

The repo has multiple folders which each have ipython notebooks, therefore just ignoring a single directory does not solve it. I want to keep adding new folders with notebooks inside without worrying about it.

My hunch is that there must be a way to use some wildcard to *gitignore anything  that is in a folder that is called */.ipynb_checkpoints/* but haven't been able to figure it out.

#### So, how can I git ignore all ipython notebook checkpoints in a repository, wherever they are?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

If you add to .gitignore:

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
```

(no slashes anywhere), any file or directory in the repo with that name will be ignored. Paths are only checked if you include `/`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/938949) you can also have a global gitignore for your computer:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'
echo '.ipynb_checkpoints' >> ~/.gitignore
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but for some reason is not working for me. From the root repository folder, my checkpoints are located in `notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/`, and I cannot for the life of me ignore them! I tried adding that path, with and without the trailing slash to my .gitignore. I tried your suggestion. I tried adding lots of stars. Any ideas?

Comment: @Engineero have you told git where your `.gitignore` file is with `git config` ?

Comment: @Engineero: have you already commited some of it ? `.gitignore` can't ignore stuff after the fact (if they are already committed)

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga it is finding my `.gitignore` just fine, and other files and folders will be ignored. I don't know why this doesn't work, but I found something that does. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I had that problem too, but I just de-indexed the files and tried something else in `.gitignore`. I was eventually able to make it work with something that I will add as an answer.

Comment: @Engineero none of the solutions work for me here. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Has anyone found a working solution yet? None of `.ipynb_checkpoints` or `*/.ipynb_checkpoints/*` seems to be working

Comment: Using `.ipynb_checkpoints` in the `.gitignore` file will works as long as none of those files are already in the git history.  I was confused why it did not seem to work until I realized someone had already commit checkpoint files.  Once I removed those everything worked fine.  I simply used `git rm .ipynb_checkpoints/*` because the files weren't large and I don't care if they are in the history.  If I had more time I would go through the process of removing the entire folder from the history.

Answer (score 37):

I would recommend to use `**/*.ipynb_checkpoints/` in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 31):

If you haven't pushed your code yet, add

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
```

to your .gitignore

If you have already pushed your code before, add
`.ipynb_checkpoints` to your .gitignore. This will ensure that .ipynb_checkpoints will be ignored in the future but doesn't remove your old .ipynb_checkpoints

You have to manually remove the cache in every folder in the respective branch. Go to the folder that has the .ipynb_checkpoints at first and do

```
git rm -r --cached .ipynb_checkpoints
```

Comment: I had this problem and looked through the various answers but this one solved it for me. In fact, I found the solution independently first and only saw this when checking. To be clear, if you have persistent files in `git status` even after you include their folder in `.gitignore`, check whether these files have previously been committed. The easiest way to do that is with the `git rm` command above. The `--cached` flag will ensure you retain a local copy.

Answer (score 22):

Add to your `.gitignore`:

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
*/.ipynb_checkpoints/*
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 8):

Some times you may forget that you are already tracking the file in your git repository (as it was in my case). So you may have to untrack it first

```
git rm --cached Folder_with_ipynb/.ipynb_checkpoints/news-checkpoint.ipynb
```

and then add to your `.gitignore` the line:

```
*/.ipynb_checkpoints/*.ipynb
```

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
Folder/.ipynb_checkpoints/*.ipynb
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, none of the current answers worked for me. I was eventually able to get git to ignore all of my checkpoint files (and any other unwanted hidden files and folders) by adding:

```sh
.*  # ignore all hidden files and folders
!/.gitignore  # explicitly do not ignore .gitignore
```

to my `.gitignore` file in the repo's base directory. This is a broad sweep, and will be a pain to maintain if you want to keep hidden files in your repo, but I have no need for any except my `.gitignore`, so it works for me!

Comment: Yes for me too none of the above works. Even what you proposed. When a checkpoint is created it appears in git status.

Comment: @pebox11 Same for me, it seemed crazily impossible to not have checkpoints, but finally Ashok Kumar's answer about cached files helped me.

Answer (score -7):

I used the command `rm -rf .ipynb_checkpoints`. This worked for me.

Comment: That is to delete the folder, not ignoring it. This is a misleading answer.

Comment: This answer is potentially dangerous to new users. Deleting the folder and adding it to .gitignore are two very different things.