# Proper way to add all directories (and sub directories in them) which have the same name in .gitignore

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a project and there are lots files with the name `.ipynb_checkpoints` or `__pycache__`. How do I add those to the gitignore. I have copied and pasted the few below but want to know the proper way.

```
*.ipynb_checkpoints
*.ipynb_checkpoints/
*.ipynb_checkpoints/.
*.ipynb_checkpoints/*
*.__pycache__
*.__pycache__/*
*.__pycache__/
*.__pycache__/.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__pycache__` folders (directories) that Python uses to store byte-compiled Python code into are most easily ignored with a single line reading:

```
__pycache__/
```

The trailing slash is optional.  Note that there is no dot `.` character here.

The `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder that Jypter uses can be ignored the same way: just list its name with an optional trailing slash.  See also [Should ipynb checkpoints be stored in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36306017/1256452) and [How to git ignore ipython notebook checkpoints anywhere in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35916658/1256452).