# Adding all .ipyn checkpoint files to git ignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I am a data scientist and I do a lot of prototyping in jupyterlab.  The problem is jupyterlabn autosaves a lot of checkpoint files and when I do git add -A this will rope them in as well forcing me to either add more pointedly (which can be annoying if I've generated a bunch of image files of plots that I want to keep) or to remove them to the commit before running git commit and pushing.  How can I add a general block on all file containing this substring `.ipynb_checkpoints` so for instance none of the checkpoint files will be included in this list:

```
new file:   .ipynb_checkpoints/High_IEG_expressing_cells-checkpoint.Rmd
#       modified:   DGC_Cck_to_Malat1_BehaviouralAxis.Rmd
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/ExcitatorySampleCorrelation-checkpoint.png
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/ExcitatorySamplesAllGenesExpression-checkpoint.png
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/Filterddata_ExcitatorySampleCorrelation-checkpoint.png
#       modified:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/Pavlab_remotememory_DEG_analysis-checkpoint.ipynb
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/RemoteMemoryMarkersExpressionSampleLevel-checkpoint.png
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/pseudobulk_sample_corrrealtionmatrix-checkpoint.jpeg
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/.ipynb_checkpoints/test-checkpoint.jpg
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/ExcitatorySampleCorrelation.png
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/ExcitatorySamplesAllGenesExpression.png
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/Filterddata_ExcitatorySampleCorrelation.png
#       modified:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/Pavlab_remotememory_DEG_analysis.ipynb
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/RemoteMemoryMarkersExpressionSampleLevel.png
#       new file:   EngramCellClassifier/Chen2020_GSE152632/pseudobulk_sample_corrrealtionmatrix.jpeg
#       modified:   High_IEG_expressing_cells.Rmd
```

Comment: `*.ipynb_checkpoints/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create a `.gitignore` file. Once you have done this you can add `.ipynb_checkpoints` to the `.gitignore`.

To do this open Git Bash and navigate to the root folder.

Then use the command `touch .gitignore`. This creates the `.gitignore` file.

Once the file has been created open it (it should be a text file) and add the text:

> .ipynb_checkpoints

Save the file.

In Git Bash make sure you are in the correct directory, then use the command `git add .gitignore`. Followed by `git commit -m "YOUR COMMENT HERE"`. Then `git push`. This should then ignore all files in the .ipynb_checkpoints folder.

To ignore them globally a solution has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916658/how-to-git-ignore-ipython-notebook-checkpoints-anywhere-in-repository).

Hope this helps.

N.B. This is also a helpful article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-file-how-to-ignore-files-and-folders-in-git/