# If I have a global .gitignore and a project local .gitignore, are they both utilized?

Tags: git

If I have [set a global .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore) and my project also has a .gitignore file and they both contain different content, do entries from both of them get used in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Together they will ignore the (union of) files they say to ignore.

This can be useful, for example:

- Globally ignore emacs/vi/whatever temp files (per local tooling)
- Project ignore build artifacts

Comment: Keep in mind that `.gitignore` files also work hierarchically within a repo. So a `.gitignore` in the root of a repo will ignore things for the whole repo, but a `.gitignore` to ignore `*.so`files within, for instance, a `build` directory of a repo will only ignore those types of files in `build` and anything below it. This lower `.gitignore` is unioned with any other `.gitignore` files higher up in the directory structure.