# How do you remove a file from the global .gitignore list in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree as my Git client for version control, and I am coming across an issue where any project I am working on is ignoring one specific file (which happens to be the main.css file).

I have checked the repository specific .gitignore file and it is empty, but the file still does not show up in my file status on Sourcetree.

How do I view the files which are being ignored globally on all projects in order to remove this file as I am currently unable to commit it to the repos and is very frustrating when more than one person is working on the same project.

Comment: Don't know Sourcetree but you can do this via **terminal**: run `git config --global core.excludesfile` and this command will output your [**Global ignore file**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/2752041). Open / edit that file to see what's being ignored globally `cat path/to/my/file`.

Comment: That's **exactly** what I needed! found that file and the main.css was sitting in there. Cheers bro

Answer (score 2):

In order to exclude a file getting ignored, add this to the project's `.gitignore`,

```
!main.css
```

This will exclude the file from getting ignored in the project.