# How to ignore files via GUI in Gitkraken?

Tags: gitkraken

I come from SourceTree to board the GitKraken hype train. It has always been pretty easy to ignore files within ST. Just right-click on a file in the unstaged container and you've all the options. You can ignore the files directly, each file beneath a specific folder etc. (so, all the .gitignore stuff from within the GUI =)).

However, I can't find a similar feature in GitKraken. Does anybody know how I can ignore files via the GUI of GitKraken?

**Please note**: This is not a git question. I absolutely know in depth how ignoring files in Git work. But that's not the topic whatsoever. **This is just a trivial GitKraken support question**.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Currently there isn't an option to ignore a file through the GitKraken GUI.
If you check their post on [twitter](https://twitter.com/gitkraken/status/703305439488958464) this is planned to be implemented soon and it will be in their [release notes](https://www.gitkraken.com/release-notes) once this is completed.

**UPDATE (26.01.2017.)**:

Version 2.0.0 brings the *.gitignore* option to the list of functionalities. You can now select a file or folder in the file staging area, and add to the .gitignore file on the fly. Right-click and select Ignore. From there, you can:

- Add that specific file to .gitignore
- Add all files with that file    extension to .gitignore
- Add all files in the same folder as the    selected file to
  .gitignore
- (If selecting a folder) add that folder    to the .gitignore

Comment: What's the difference of "Ignore" and "Ignore and Stop Tracking"?

Comment: @LucasBustamante "Ignore" simply adds the file(type) to the .gitignore file so that new files with that name/type/whatever are not tracked. To "stop tracking" means to remove the file(s) from git version control: they will no longer be in the repo (as of the commit that performs the "stop tracking"). Basically, use the "stop tracking" if the file(s) you are ignoring never should have been in the repo in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just right click on the file you added/changed and you will see the Ignore option.

Comment: @MarkoLetic: Hi, can we use our gitignore_global file with GitKraken yet?

Comment: Unfortunately global gitignore file is still not supported.

Comment: good answer. select "tree" option in top of unstaged files and choose folder and easily ignore that

Comment: global git ignore is working now. Try to reopen your repository tab in gitkraken.
More about using global gitignore here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore