# How to ignore directory globally in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to completely ignore .idea folders in all my Git repositories. I want my repositories to not even know about files in this folder, so placing `.gitignore` file each time is not an option. I tried to globally set `core.excludesfile` in my global Git config, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = .idea/**
```

Plus, it overwrites my system ignores, like `.DS_STORE` files. How can I ignore `.idea` folders entirely without letting know my repositories about these folders?

Comment: It's always a good idea to have a git project self-contained, i.e. not depend on global settings. Do you really create a new git project so often?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore ?

Answer (score 5):

As described in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), `core.excludesFile` is not a pattern, but rather the name of a file that *contains* patterns:

> `core.excludesFile`
>
> Specifies the pathname to the file that contains patterns to describe paths that are not meant to be tracked, in addition to *.gitignore* (per-directory) and *.git/info/exclude*. Defaults to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` is used instead. See [gitignore(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

Hence you should be putting `.idea/**` (or just `.idea` or `.idea/*`) in some file, and pointing `core.excludesFile` to that file if that is not already the default file.