# User specific files to exclude in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have been using git for some time now. For my project, I have created a `.gitignore` file which works well. As the project grows, I have started creating some files of my own (logs, scripts and so on) which I don't want to include in the repository. As of now, when I type `git status`, I see these files listed and I simply ignore them (which becomes more and more annoying as the list grows). The problem is that I also don't want to pollute the repo's public `.gitignore` file by adding all my personal stuff to it.

Is there a way to hide these files when I `git status`?

I have looked for some `#include`-like directive which all user could use to insert a personal list, but have found nothing so far. Does such an option exist?

Comment: @torek I would say that this is not a dupe of that question - OP does not necessarily want to apply the ignore rules globally. A more appropriate solution would be to use `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: A better dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally

Comment: @1615903: I'll buy that.  Both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore are potential dups, depending on one's goals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Comment: +1 for the `.git/info/exclude` mentioned in the dup question, but do not run the `git update-index --assume-unchanged` command on any of your files