# CSProj files not pushed to version control

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to push my source code (Xamarin.Forms) to a Visual Studio Team Services' Version Control instance. I'm working with the latest stable version of Visual Studio for Mac.

Problem is though that every time I push the code, my CSproj files aren't being uploaded.

Is there a setting or something like it I should change?

Comment: Are you using git or tfs?

Comment: With the word "push" I assume you're using git. git only pushes your commits, and if you didn't commit your .csproj files, obviously there's no commit that contains those file and thus "they" won't get pushed either. You need to add the .csproj files to your repository and commit them. If you're using TFS source control, not git, you need to do the same, add the .csproj files to source control before checking in.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes I am using git, and yes I have made the commit. But it does not appear in it, almost as if it is ignored but its not in my gitignore.

Comment: @Asken Im using git.

Comment: do you have a .gitignore? There is no reason for git to ignore csproj (unless you tell it to). Without a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Liam Yes I do, it's not in there. Even when I removed the .gitignore it does not commit.

Comment: What about a [global .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore) try `git config --get core.excludesfile`

Comment: Run `git status` in a console. Does it show files modified? If not, change a file and run `git status` again.