# Is there any git directory that can be definitely and always ignored by default?

Tags: git

I would like to ignore `sandbox` directories located in my project directory. However, by default, if there are some same directory that can be always ignored w/o any configuration, I would love to use and should use it.

So, my question is `Is there any git directory that can be definitely and always ignored by default?`

Comment: AFAIK anything inside the `.git` folder is fair game for being tracked.  But of course, you may put your folder outside of that directory, and then Git would know nothing about it.

Comment: You can configure one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335420/124319

Comment: Create a global gitignore file, and put in 'sandbox' or w/e.

Comment: Thank you, guys. So, the solution has the only way that you need to add `sandbox/` to my `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Yes, but you can add it to the global gitignore file, see the link above.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create a global `.gitignore`:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.config/git/ignore
```

for instance; see [Global Git ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335420/1256452) for much more about this.

Note, however, that in many cases, you *should not* do this.  (This same idea is captured in the second answer on that page, which is not the accepted answer.)

For files that are created by something *you* do, that *won't* be created for other people doing work in the same project, a global `.gitignore` is appropriate.  For instance, suppose that all of your coworkers use the vim or emacs or sublime editor, but you use your own personal editor, perhaps called Frank's Editor, and it creates backup files named `.frank.<name>`.

You would want all *your* Git repositories to ignore `.frank.*` as those are *your* editor backups.  They're not Bob's editor backups, which are `*.~` because he uses emacs, and they're not Carol's `.*.swp` vim temporaries.  Your project shouldn't ignore `*.~` either—that should be in Bob's global ignore, and Carol should have `.*.swp` in her global ignore.

But if your project has a `sandbox/` subdirectory that the *project* uses, that you, Bob, and Carol will all have in your project—well, *that* file-name should be in the project's `.gitignore` file, so that it's ignored in your clone, in Bob's clone, in Carol's clone, and in every other clone anyone ever makes, because that project's `.gitignore` gets cloned along with the project.