# excluding everything from git except

Tags: git

I have the following file structure and I would like to track `.ddd/zzz` and `.aaa` and their subfolders with git, and exclude everything else.

```
.aaa/
.aaa/file.txt
.bbb/
.bbb/www
.bbb/www/www
.bbb/www/www/file.txt
.ccc/
.ddd/
.ddd/zzz
.ddd/zzz/file.txt
.eee/
```

I have this in my `.gitignore` file:

```
*
!.aaa/
!.ddd/zzz/
.gitignore
```

yet when I initialize the repository, I get *nothing to commit*.

**How can I exclude everything but these two directories and their content?**

Comment: You should not ignore your own `.gitignore`!

Comment: @Ulysse BN - why not?

Comment: Because a `.gitignore` file should be shared. If you don't want to share some exclude rules you could use the file `.git/info/exclude` or set-up a [global git ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/6320039).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying some configurations, I came across with the solution. Having my repo with:

```sh
# tree -a
.
├── .git/*
├── .gitignore
├── a
│   └── should-be-taken.txt
├── b
│   └── should-be-ignored.txt
└── recursive
    ├── folder
    │   └── should-be-taken.txt
    └── no.txt
```

I got a solution with:

```sh
# cat .gitignore
*
!/a
!/a/**
!/recursive
!/recursive/folder
!/recursive/folder/**
!.gitignore
```

The key is to explicitly negate the whole folder path you want to not be ignored within your *.gitignore* file. And then `**` matches everything inside, cf [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.

---

**EDIT:** Even though my solution still works, there is another way shown in the [gitignore Documentation Examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_examples):

> Example to exclude everything except a specific directory `foo/bar` (note the `/*` - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within `foo/bar`):
>
> ```
> # exclude everything except directory foo/bar
> /*
> !/foo
> /foo/*
> !/foo/bar
> ```