# How to globally ignore the .idea/ folder in git (not just adding it to .gitignore)

Tags: windows, git, global

O., I am wondering if there is a way to globally ignore the .idea folder on my machine? I don't have or need a .gitignore file in my project, but it is irritating that the .idea/ folder keeps appearing when trying to add and commit real changes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Configure the path to the global .gitignore in the .gitconfig file which usually resides in your home directory:

```
# add this to ~/.gitconfig:
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

- And create the .gitignore file in your home directory:

```
# create ~/.gitignore

.idea
```

.idea will be ignored in any git repository on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

This is straight from `git help ignore`:

> Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by core.excludesFile in the user’s `~/.gitconfig`. Its default value is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer here already: [See CB Baileys answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)

It involves setting a gitignore file 'somewhere'. Specify where, by using the command given by on that link.

Then you need to actually create the file at `~/.gitignore`, adding `.vscode` or in your case, `.idea` there.