# How to add in git ignore files with ._ in front of the file name?

Tags: github

My external HDD is creating some files with ._ in front of the file name like `Podfile` and `._Podfile` and I would like to know if is a way to ignore those files form pushing to GitHub

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it with the dot just add:

```
._Podfile
```

to your `.gitignore`

if you want to ignore all files starting with `._` you can add `._*` to your `.gitignore`

**But** because it is only your HDD creating those `._Podfile`s you could also add

```
._Podfile
```

to your "global git ignore" read more about global git ignore file here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/2008111

With the global git ignore you are saying to ignore it for every git project on your system! But without committing it to the project. Which in my opinion in this case is where it belongs.