# What files need to be uploaded or added to the git repository if I'm making a pip module

Tags: python, git, module, pip, gitignore

I recently made an open-source pip module and I and to publish it is PyPI. I know on the PyPI, I can directly publish the modules `dist/*` folder using `twine` but I also want to publish this module on GitHub, Gitlab & My own organization's official git repo. So, I was wondering which files should I add to the `git` repository?

[image: My project structure]

**`src` Folder:** This is the main folder of my file that I codded my python modules.

So on the git repository should I upload:

1. All the files (No **`venv`** folder)
2. **`dist`** Folder, **`src`** Folder, **`.gitinore`**, **`LICENSE`**, **`README.md`**, **`setup.py`**
3. Option **(2)** without the  **`src`** Folder
4. Option **(2)** without the  **`dist`** Folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to include the `src` folder, `.gitinore`, `LICENSE`, `README.md`, and `setup.py`. Ideally you always want to re-build before publishing to Pypi, so you do not need the `dist` folder.

However, I recommend using the dependency management tool [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), which uses a `pyproject.toml` instead of the `setup.py`. It's much more human-readable and easier to manage than the old-fashioned `setup.py`.

poetry also allows publishing your package to Pypi with a single command `poetry publish --build ...`.

Comment: Do I also need to add the **`*.egg-info`** folder that is under the src folder to the git?

Comment: No, typically there are also a few other files in Python projects you do not want to keep, e.g. IDE files such as `.idea/`/`.vscode`, Python-specific files such as `*.egg-info/`, `__pycache__/`, and `*.pyc`. I also recommed you to set up a global gitignore file (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)) to avoid that you push any such files to any other repo you ever work on.