# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest appending to a file instead of writing

Tags: powershell, append, invoke-webrequest

PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest` provides `-OutFile` that **writes** the response body to a file.

```
@('Global/JetBrains','Global/Vim','Global/VisualStudioCode','Global/macOS','Python','Terraform') `
  | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Outfile "$Env:USERPROFILE/.gitignore" -Uri `
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/$PSItem.gitignore"
  }
```

I would like to **append** to the file `$Env:USERPROFILE/.gitignore`, and it doesn't seem like `Invoke-WebRequest` will support this.  How can I go about doing this?

Also, any tips on how I can make this PowerShell script more readable/concise?

Note: I am using PowerShell version `5.1.19041.1237`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do not use `-OutFile`, which doesn't support *appending* to a file; instead, output the response text to the success output stream (pipeline).

  - Using [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) rather than [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) is simpler, as it outputs the response text *directly*.
- Pipe the result to [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) in order to append to the target file.

Note: As later requested, the target file path has been corrected per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885996/11163122), and the existence of the target directory is ensured.

```
# Make sure that the platform-appropriate target dir. exists.
$outDir = ("$HOME/.config/git", "$HOME/git")[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT']
$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force $outDir

'Global/JetBrains', 'Global/Vim', 'Global/VisualStudioCode', 'Global/macOS', 'Python', 'Terraform' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/$PSItem.gitignore"
  } | 
    Add-Content $outDir/ignore
```

Comment: Thank you @mklement0!  I have just learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885996/11163122) that the default path is actually `%USERPROFILE%\git\ignore`, if anyone else cares about the `.gitignore` specifics

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer, I've updated the answer again to make it cross-platform.