# Git ignoring folder not in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git directory as follows:

[image]

My `.gitignore` contains:

[image]

`git status` returns the following:

[image]

`git status --ignored` returns:

[image]

Directory `template` is a regular directory that isn't a part of any other git project. It contains the following:

[image]

`git config --get core.excludesfile` returns:

[image]

Any ideas why `git` is ignoring the directory `template` ? I even deleted the `.git` folder and re-initialized git but still the same thing is happening.

Comment: Do you have any [global ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335420/3001761) configured?

Comment: @jonrsharpe none. Just the default git configuration

Comment: Did you check the `core.excludesfile` config value? Maybe it's set to something you don't remember

Comment: Since you have ignored css, html, png, is there anything in the template folder that *isn't* ignored? By that I mean, shouldn't match any of the gitignore rules.

Comment: @CherryDT I just did, it returns nothing (added the screenshot in the question)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen not really. But the files I've ignored are for the root directory. The rule shouldn't apply to the subdirectory. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks!! changing `*.html` to `./*.html` and similarly for other files fixed the issue

Comment: @CherryDT version is `git version 2.34.1.windows.1` and `git check-ignore -v template/` returns blank

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function [`check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to debug this problem:

```
git check-ignore -v template/
```

The output will be in the following format:

```
someGitignoreFile:123:someRule   template/
```

...pointing you to the exact gitignore file, line number and particular ignore rule that led to the exclusion of `template/`.

If this comes up empty, then the next possibility is that even though the folder itself is technically not ignored, every single file inside of it is, and since Git tracks files and not empty folders (you cannot add an empty folder to the index), this would have the same result and is abbreviated in `git status --ignored` as showing the whole folder as ignored. You could check for that by going through all the files and checking them `check-ignore` as well - in your case it's possible that for example there are only `*.html`, `*.png` and `*.js` files inside `template/`, all of which you ignored in your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't track folders, only files. It looks like you've excluded every type of file that's likely to live in that folder since the ignore of `*.css, *.jpd etc` is recursive actors all subfolders. If there are no files left in the templates folder, then get won't track it.