# How to manage .tool-versions for current directory without storing it in current directory

Tags: asdf-vm

I've come to love what asdf does for my onboarding story in projects that i have control over.

However for projects where there is a strange mandate that it must use nvm and must not migrate to asdf for whatever reason, i'd like a way to utilise `.tool-versions` for certain directories that are unable to have this commited:

maybe something like:

```
~/.asdf/projects/
  home_me_projects_clientname_projectname.toolversions
  home_me_projects_someotherclientname_projectname.toolversions
```

then perhaps some kind of direnv magic in my `~/.tool-versions` and `~/.direnv` that magically picks the right one above depending on what directory i'm in?

anybody else had a need for such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to work around that requirement:

1. If you want to have a `.tool-versions` file for your projects, but never commit them to Git, try setting up a global gitignore for your `.tool-versions` files. Then you can use them anywhere and never worry about committing them to any project. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/1245380).
2. Wrap each project directory in an outer directory containing just a `.tool-versions` file for the project. For example:

   ```
   ~/projects
   |--project_1
   |  |--.tool-versions
   |  |--project_1
   |--project_2
   |  |--.tool-versions
   |  |--project_2
   ```

   This ensures the version info from the `.tool-versions` files are used when you are working on the source code in the inner `project_1` and `project_2` directories
3. Use the nodejs plugins legacy version file support to read the versions from `.nvmrc` or `.node-version` files: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs#nvmrc-and-node-version-support