# VSCode filname greyed out, its not the .gitignore file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally pressed a key combo and now it won't push some of my files. This is my .gitignore:

```
build
dist
node_modules
package-lock.json
.env
.next
.vercel
```

Can anyone help me get the keycombo? I might have mispressed something.

I looked into the gitignore file, and the keycombo file, but I don't know whats the problem.

[image: greyed out]

Comment: Do you have a [global .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore) ? Or maybe another .gitignore file was created with the keycombo somewhere in your repo.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving when you attempt to push some files?

Comment: I redid the project since I haven't found a solution...